# Find coordinates of point C in a equilateral triangle

Tags: vectors, triangles, coordinate-systems

How to find the coordinates of point C in a equilateral triangle, where $A=(-2,2)$ and $B=(6,2)$.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/TXjjG.png

Thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome to MSE. You will find a helpful guide to formatting the math parts of questions here http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation

Comment: Do you mean the coordinates of $A$ and $B$ are $(-2,2)$ and $(6,2)$? If so, can't you figure out at least the $x$-coordinate of $C$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint:

1) note that $\overline {AB}=8$.

2) Note that $C$ isa point on the line orthogonal to $AB$ in the middle point, so it is  a point on the vertical line $x=2$. This means that $C$ has coordinates $C=(2,y)$

3) You want $\overline{AB}=\overline{AC}$ and this gives an equation that you can solve for $y$ and gives two results (why?)

---

You have $\overline{AC}=\sqrt{(2+2)^2+(y-2)^2}=\sqrt{16+(y-2)^2}$, so the equation that you have to solve is:
$$
64=16+y^2+4-4y \quad \iff \quad y^2-4y-44=0
$$

can you solve it?

Comment: After following these steps, I got this equations (8/0) = (4/y-2) and I am not really sure how to solve it.

Comment: I've added to my answer. Can you solve?

Comment: Yes I can solve it, just how did You get 64 from AC?

Comment: $AC=AB=8$ and, squaring because we have a square root at RHS, $8^2=64$

Comment: Thank You for your help :)

Comment: Just one more question, what formula did You use in order to get the equation, is there a specific formula for it? Since there is (2+2) under the square root and the equation I got was (8/0), (4/y-2).

Comment: The formula for the euclidean distance of two points in  a plane: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_distance#Two_dimensions